# ggplot2 barplot bar colour can't be changed properly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created the following flipped bar plot in ggplot2 (a coordinate flipped grouped bar plot in bright green) - which worked out just fine (Code 1).

However I tried to recreate the same plot structure with different data, basically copying and adapting the code from the first plot. Everything is fine, exept for the colour being grey instead of the desired green in the scale fill manual. I honestly can't figure out why it works in the first plot but not in the second. (Code 2)

CODE 1 (the working original plot)

```
#LIBRARIES
library (ggplot2)
library (dplyr)
library (data.table)
library (rdrop2)
library(tableHTML)
library (forcats)
  
  df<- data.frame(
    Komp = rep(c("Geschlecht", "Alter", "Niveau"), 6), 
    
    groupW = c(
      rep("1", 3),
      rep("2", 3),
      rep("3", 3),
      NA, NA, "4",
      NA, NA, "5",
      NA, NA, "6"
      
      
      
    ),
    
    
    valuesW = c (45, 14.9, 4.6, 54, 64.9, 5.3, 1, 19.8, 22.2, NA, NA, 15.4, NA, NA, 38.2, NA, NA, 14.2)
    
  ) 



df%>%
  ggplot( aes(x = fct_rev(Komp), y = valuesW, fill = fct_rev(groupW))) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity",color = "#404040", show.legend = FALSE, 
             #width = 1
    )+
    #scale_fill_discrete(name = "Vergleichsgruppen", labels=c("Du", "Gesamtdurchschnitt", paste("Durchschnitt", (Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP01_01"]-1),"-",(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP01_01"]+1), "Jahre" ),paste("Durchschnitt",Daten[toupper(input$Code), "Sportart_zurueckkodiert"]), Geschlecht))+
    xlab("")+
    ylab("Prozent")+
    scale_fill_manual(values=rep( "#8DAE10", 6))+
    coord_flip()+
    #geom_hline(yintercept = 10, lty = 8, col = "Red")
    geom_text(
      aes (label = ifelse(is.na(valuesW),"" ,paste(valuesW,"%"))),
      color = "black", hjust =-0.35 , size = 4, position = position_dodge(width= 0.9))+
    
    #scale_x_discrete(limits= rev(levels(groupW)))+
    geom_text(aes(y=0, label = c(
      "Weiblich",  "10-13 Jahre","Keine Ebene",
      "Mxnnlich", "14-17 Jahre","Bezirksebene", 
      "Div.",  "18-23 Jahre","Landesebene",
      "", "",  "landesxbergreifende Ebene" , 
      "", "",  "nationale Ebene", 
      "","", "internationale Ebene")
    ),  color = "white", hjust = 0, size = 5, position = position_dodge(width= 0.9))+
    scale_y_continuous(
      expand= c(0.04,0), label = scales::comma, position = "right"
    )
```

CODE 2 (a grey plot that is supposed to be just as green as the first one)

```
#LIBRARIES
library (ggplot2)
library (dplyr)
library (data.table)
library (rdrop2)
library(tableHTML)
library (forcats)


df<- data.frame(

  
  
  
    
  Komp = rep(c("Smartphone", "PC/Laptop", "Tablet", "TV", "Spielkonsole", "Smart-Watch", "E-Book-Reader", "Andere"), 2), 
  
  groupW = c(
    rep("ja", 8),
    rep("nein", 8)
    
    
    
  ),
  
  
  valuesW = c (100-0, 100-23.9, 100-41.3, 100-30.9, 100-51.5, 100-73.2, 100-89.8, 100-98.9 ,0, 23.9, 41.3, 30.9, 51.5, 73.2, 89.8, 98.9)
  
) 

df%>%
  ggplot( aes(x = fct_rev(Komp), y = valuesW, fill = fct_rev(groupW))) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity",color = "#8DAE10", show.legend = FALSE, 
             #width = 1
    )+
    #scale_fill_discrete(name = "Vergleichsgruppen", labels=c("Du", "Gesamtdurchschnitt", paste("Durchschnitt", (Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP01_01"]-1),"-",(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP01_01"]+1), "Jahre" ),paste("Durchschnitt",Daten[toupper(input$Code), "Sportart_zurueckkodiert"]), Geschlecht))+
    xlab("")+
    ylab("Prozent")+
    scale_fill_manual(values=rep( "#8DAE10", 16), limits = c("Smartphone", "PC/Laptop", "Tablet", "TV", "Spielkonsole", "Smart-Watch", "E-Book-Reader", "Andere"))+
    coord_flip()+
    #geom_hline(yintercept = 10, lty = 8, col = "Red")
    geom_text(
      aes (label = round(valuesW,1)),
      color = "black", hjust =-0.35 , size = 4, position = position_dodge(width= 0.9))+
    
    #scale_x_discrete(limits= rev(levels(groupW)))+
    geom_text(aes(y=0, label = groupW
    ),  color = "white", hjust = 0, size = 5, position = position_dodge(width= 0.9))+
    scale_y_continuous(
      expand= c(0.04,0), label = scales::comma, position = "right"
    )
```

Any ideas where the mistake is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these adjustments to
a) achieve the green bar colour and
b) simplify the code

1. use `geom_col` rather than `geom_bar` with stat = "identity"
2. swap x and y values and associated scales etc to avoid using coord_flip
3. remove the `limits` argument in the call to `scale_fill_manual`
4. convert `Komp` to a factor to control order of values in ggplot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)


komp_cat <- c("Smartphone", "PC/Laptop", "Tablet", "TV", "Spielkonsole", "Smart-Watch", "E-Book-Reader", "Andere")

df1<- data.frame(
  Komp = rep(komp_cat, 2), 
  
  groupW = c(
    rep("ja", 8),
    rep("nein", 8)),
  
  valuesW = c (100-0, 100-23.9, 100-41.3, 100-30.9, 100-51.5, 100-73.2, 100-89.8, 100-98.9 ,0, 23.9, 41.3, 30.9, 51.5, 73.2, 89.8, 98.9)
  
) 



df1 %>% 
  mutate(Komp = factor(Komp, levels = komp_cat)) %>% 
  ggplot( aes(x = valuesW, y = fct_rev(Komp), fill = rev(groupW))) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "#8DAE10", show.legend = FALSE)+
  xlab("Prozent")+
  ylab("")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep("#8DAE10", 2))+
  geom_text(aes (label = round(valuesW,1)),
            color = "black", 
            hjust = -0.35, 
            size = 4, 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))+
  geom_text(aes(x=0, label = groupW),
            color = "white", 
            hjust = 0, 
            size = 5, 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.04, 0), label = scales::comma, position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: As I already told @Godrim I need the exact order of the categories though and if I delete the limits argument I may have solved the one issue but be stuck with a different one.

Comment: The values of `Komp` and `groupW` are in alphabetical order (both in the dataframe and in ggplot); What is the order you want them to be in? Deleting the limits in your CODE 2 example makes no difference to the order of `Komp` and `groupW` values. It might be easier and less confusing to ask a new question with this new condition, rather than adjust the question. Usually adjusting the factor levels of a categorical variable is best done outside the call to `ggplot`

Comment: Both your codes 2 and 3 have an "Andere"  (== other) category is this what is causing the issue?

Comment: In the dataframe their order is this c("Smartphone", "PC/Laptop", "Tablet", "TV", "Spielkonsole", "Smart-Watch", "E-Book-Reader", "Andere") which is basically ordered by how big the "yes" bars are but "other" being the last category. In the data frame they're of course ordered alphabetically, but I'd like to change it back. I THOUGHT from a previous project that could be done from the scale_fill_manual aswell but I think I confused something there.

Comment: Leave the question as not only is it a legitimate question but it may also be useful for others.

Comment: Updated answer to demonstrate how to control order of values in `Komp`

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `limits = c("Smartphone", "PC/Laptop", "Tablet", "TV", "Spielkonsole", "Smart-Watch", "E-Book-Reader", "Andere")`

It should make all the bars the wanted green colour.

```
library (ggplot2)
library (dplyr)
library (data.table)
library (rdrop2)
library(tableHTML)
library (forcats)


df<- data.frame(

  
  
  
    
  Komp = rep(c("Smartphone", "PC/Laptop", "Tablet", "TV", "Spielkonsole", "Smart-Watch", "E-Book-Reader", "Andere"), 2), 
  
  groupW = c(
    rep("ja", 8),
    rep("nein", 8)
    
    
    
  ),
  
  
  valuesW = c (100-0, 100-23.9, 100-41.3, 100-30.9, 100-51.5, 100-73.2, 100-89.8, 100-98.9 ,0, 23.9, 41.3, 30.9, 51.5, 73.2, 89.8, 98.9)
  
) 

df%>%
  ggplot( aes(x = fct_rev(Komp), y = valuesW, fill = fct_rev(groupW))) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity",color = "#8DAE10", show.legend = FALSE, 
             #width = 1
    )+
    #scale_fill_discrete(name = "Vergleichsgruppen", labels=c("Du", "Gesamtdurchschnitt", paste("Durchschnitt", (Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP01_01"]-1),"-",(Daten[toupper(input$Code), "SP01_01"]+1), "Jahre" ),paste("Durchschnitt",Daten[toupper(input$Code), "Sportart_zurueckkodiert"]), Geschlecht))+
    xlab("")+
    ylab("Prozent")+
    scale_fill_manual(values=rep( "#8DAE10", 16), )+
    coord_flip()+
    #geom_hline(yintercept = 10, lty = 8, col = "Red")
    geom_text(
      aes (label = round(valuesW,1)),
      color = "black", hjust =-0.35 , size = 4, position = position_dodge(width= 0.9))+
    
    #scale_x_discrete(limits= rev(levels(groupW)))+
    geom_text(aes(y=0, label = groupW
    ),  color = "white", hjust = 0, size = 5, position = position_dodge(width= 0.9))+
    scale_y_continuous(
      expand= c(0.04,0), label = scales::comma, position = "right"
    )
```